Using hxselect Command in Bash: How to Store Output in Arrays?
I'm trying to use curl in Bash to fetch data from a web page using this script.
#!/bin/bash

# Define variables for URL and browser
sGCitta="fucecchio"
sGTypo="sale-houses"
sGDomain="real-estate"
url="https://www.$sGDomain.it/$sGTypo/$sGCitta"

# Get HTML content of the page
html_content=$(curl -s -L "$url")

# Use html-xml-utils to extract announcements
announcements=$(echo "$html_content" | hxselect 'li.nd-list__item.in-searchLayoutListItem')

# Connect to SQLite database
db_file="immo.db"

# Initialize arrays for prices, links, descriptions, sizes, and auction
prices=()
links=()
descriptions=()
sizes=()
auctions=()

# Loop through the announcements
while IFS= read -r announcement; do
    # Extract price
    price=$(echo "$announcement" | hxselect 'div.in-listingCardPrice span' -c | grep -oP '(?<=€ )[0-9,.]+')

    # Extract link
    link=$(echo "$announcement" | hxselect 'a.in-listingCardTitle' -s '\n' | grep -o 'href="[^"]*"' | sed 's/^href="//' | sed 's/"$//')

    # Extract description
    description=$(echo "$announcement" | hxselect 'a.in-listingCardTitle' -s '\n' | grep -oP '(?<=title=")[^"]+')

    # Extract size
    size=$(echo "$announcement" | hxselect 'div.in-listingCardFeatureList__item:nth-of-type(2) span' -c | grep -oP '[0-9]+')

    # Check if the description contains the word "auction"
    if [[ "$description" =~ "auction" ]]; then
        auction=1
    else
        auction=0
    fi

    # Add data to the arrays
    prices+=("$price")
    links+=("$link")
    descriptions+=("$description")
    sizes+=("$size")
    auctions+=("$auction")

done <<< "$announcements"

# Print the sizes of the arrays
echo "Size of the prices array: ${#prices[@]}"
echo "Size of the links array: ${#links[@]}"
echo "Size of the descriptions array: ${#descriptions[@]}"
echo "Size of the sizes array: ${#sizes[@]}"
echo "Size of the auctions array: ${#auctions[@]}"

# Insert data into the SQLite database
for ((i = 0; i < ${#prices[@]}; i++)); do
    sqlite3 "$db_file" "INSERT INTO $sGDomain (price, link, description, size, auction) VALUES ('${prices[i]}', '${links[i]}', '${descriptions[i]}', '${sizes[i]}', '${auctions[i]}')"
done

Currently, it places all the data related to prices (for example, price) in prices[1]. However, I'd like it to put the first price in prices[1] and the second price in prices[2], but I'm not sure how to accomplish this. Can anyone give me a hint?
I tried using the 'hxselect' command to extract data from the web page and store it in arrays. However, the data for prices was all stored in the same array index (prices[1]) instead of being distributed across different indices based on the position of the prices on the web page. I expected that the prices would be stored in different array indices corresponding to their position on the page

Have you tried readarray? It's a bash built-in command.

Having a sample of the HTML page would be great

@Fravadona
https://www.immobiliare.it/vendita-case/fucecchio/

Include the html document in the body of the question, not a link

Your question needs to contain all the necessary information within the question itself (not in comments, behind external links, or in images or videos) and ideally nothing else.

Did you consider using a XPath processor instead of hxselect | grep | sed | etc…

As long as the processor understands HTML5 you can use XPath to extract data from the URL that you provided. With that in mind, I would recommend xidel (available here for a few OSs) for your task.
So here's a solution that extracts the data with XPath 3.1 and outputs it as JSON (CSV is also possible); then you just have to import it in SQlite using the method provided in this post:
edit: replaced exit 1 with exit for keeping the exit status of the xidel command in case of failure (Thanks @CharlesDuffy)
xidel --xpath '
  array{
    //li//div[@class => contains-token("in-listingCardPropertyContent")] ! (
      let
        $priceStrings := div[contains-token(@class,"in-listingCardPrice")]/string(),
        $sizeStrings  := div/div[svg/use/@href = "#size"]/string(),
        $titleNodes   := a[@class => contains-token("in-listingCardTitle")],
        $linkStrings  := $titleNodes/@href/string(),
        $descStrings  := $titleNodes/@title/string()
      return map{
        "price"       : $priceStrings => tokenize() => filter(matches(?,"^[\d.,]+$")),
        "link"        : $linkStrings  => replace("^\s+|\s+$",""),
        "description" : $descStrings  => replace("^\s+|\s+$",""),
        "size"        : $sizeStrings  => tokenize() => filter(matches(?,"^[\d.,]+$")),
        "auction"     : $descStrings  => contains("auction")
      }
    )
  }
' "$url" > data.json || exit

sqlite3 "$db_file" "
    INSERT INTO "$sGDomain" (price, link, description, size, auction)
    SELECT
        json_extract(value, '\$.price'),
        json_extract(value, '\$.link'),
        json_extract(value, '\$.description'),
        json_extract(value, '\$.size'),
        json_extract(value, '\$.auction')
    FROM json_each(readfile('data.json'));
"

note: I made the script exit when the XPath query fails because it's important to not import junk into the DB. The current XPath code is already quite finicky but it won't fail when some data is missing (which can happen if the site decide to update their front-end). Dowloading the HTML page into a file with curl and passing that file to xidel might become handy for debugging purposes.

ASIDE Here's a sample of xidel's output with the URL that you provided:
[
  {
    "price": "6.300.000",
    "link": "https://.../112293455/",
    "description": "Villa unifamiliare via delle Forre Torre 8, Fucecchio",
    "size": "1.600",
    "auction": false
  },
  {
    "price": "168.750,00",
    "link": "https://.../112298799/",
    "description": "Appartamento all'asta via Trento, 147, Fucecchio",
    "size": "212",
    "auction": false
  },
  ...
]

